# Package Creation Error

Tags: 15.04, packaging, debian, debuild

I was experimenting with building packages, and I got into a bit of a trouble. After setting everything up, I ran

```
dch -i
```

And edited the changelog to look like this:

```
packagekit-qt (0.9.5-2ubuntu2) wily; urgency=medium

  * A new package

 -- Ranveer Aggarwal <me@ranveeraggarwal.com>  Wed, 27 May 2015 21:26:46 +0530

packagekit-qt (0.8.8-2ubuntu1) saucy; urgency=low

  * Merge from Debian unstable (LP: #1217699). Remaining changes:
    + Add alternative recommendation of python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat

 -- Sebastian Heinlein <glatzor@ubuntu.com>  Wed, 28 Aug 2013 07:14:56 +0200

packagekit-qt (0.8.8-2) unstable; urgency=low

  * Upload to unstable

 -- Matthias Klumpp <mak@debian.org>  Sun, 23 Jun 2013 22:42:21 +0200

packagekit-qt (0.8.8-1) experimental; urgency=low

  * New upstream release: 0.8.8
  * Do not depend on system-interface virtual package
  * Adjust packaging to SONAME bump

 -- Matthias Klumpp <mak@debian.org>  Tue, 04 Jun 2013 14:50:38 +0200

packagekit-qt (0.8.7-2) experimental; urgency=low

  * New upstream release: 0.8.7

 -- Matthias Klumpp <mak@debian.org>  Tue, 19 Mar 2013 20:34:27 +0100

packagekit-qt (0.8.6-1) unstable; urgency=low

  * Initial release (Closes: #468132)

 -- Matthias Klumpp <matthias@tenstral.net>  Sun, 02 Dec 2012 22:17:35 +0100
```

And then, I ran

```
debuild
```

but, I was greeted by the following error:

```
This package has a Debian revision number but there does not seem to be
an appropriate original tar file or .orig directory in the parent directory;
(expected one of packagekit-qt_0.9.5.orig.tar.gz, packagekit-qt_0.9.5.orig.tar.bz2,
packagekit-qt_0.9.5.orig.tar.lzma,  packagekit-qt_0.9.5.orig.tar.xz or new.orig)
continue anyway? (y/n) y
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: source package packagekit-qt
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 0.9.5-2ubuntu2
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution wily
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Ranveer Aggarwal <me@ranveeraggarwal.com>
 dpkg-source --before-build new
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean --parallel
   dh_testdir -O--parallel
   dh_auto_clean -O--parallel
   dh_clean -O--parallel
 dpkg-source -b new
dpkg-source: error: can't build with source format '3.0 (quilt)': no upstream tarball found at ../packagekit-qt_0.9.5.orig.tar.{bz2,gz,lzma,xz}
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b new gave error exit status 255
debuild: fatal error at line 1376:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

Doing an `ls` in my main directory returns this:

```
debian  packagekit-qt_0.9.5.orig.tar.xz
```

Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: The tarball should be in the grandparent directory of `debian`, IIRC. The path should look like this: `foo->packagekit-qt->debian`, `foo->packagekit-qt_0.9.5.orig.tar.xz`. Do everything relative to `packagekit-qt`.

Comment: You're right. That was the only mistake :/ This was kinda my first time packaging, so I seem to have to made a silly mistake. I'll do more research before posting a doubt here next time.

Comment: That's okay. At least your folders don't have version numbers in the name. If that was all, I'll post it as answer.

Comment: Yep! Please post it as an answer. Just putting the same version number as the folder name works. Basically, `debian` should have been in the source folder

Comment: It will work, but dch -i will rename the directory as well when changing the version. Made my first few tries very annoying since your $PWD is no longer a valid path. Took me ages to figure out I didn't need the number there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tarball should be in the grandparent directory of `debian`. The layout should look like this:

- `foo->packagekit-qt->debian`
- `foo->packagekit-qt_0.9.5.orig.tar.xz`.

Do everything relative to `packagekit-qt`.